# Validation with request to the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-validation

I have three models : `User`, `Product` and `Loan`. A loan has a `borrowing_date`, a `returning_date` and a `current` boolean.

- I want to prevent a user to ask borrowing a product more than once.
- I want to prevent my loan model to have more than one current loan.

How can I do that ?

Here are my trials, but it didn't came out right :

```rb
def only_one_current_loan
  errors.add(:current, I18n.t('validation.loan.only_one_current')) unless Loan.find_by(product: self.product, current: true).count < 1
end

def only_one_request_at_a_time
  errors.add(:product_id, I18n.t('validation.loan.only_one_request_at_a_time')) unless Loan.where(product_id: self.product.id, user_id: self.user.id, borrowing_date: nil).count < 1
end
```

Comment: Are you calling from a callback instead of validation?

Comment: I'm using `validate only_one_current_loan` and `validate only_one_request_at_a_time`.

Comment: I guess you'll need to symbolize them. `validate :only_one_current_loan`

Comment: It's a typing mistake in my comment. I really wrote `validate :only_one_current_loan` in my model...

Comment: `.nil? < 1` This seems fishy. nil? will return true or false. which doesn't respond to <. It is best to debug things in such cases. Add a debugger there and check the `unless` conditions.

Comment: Oops, I wrote that question way too fast. It's not `.nil?` but `.count`... Sorry for the inconvenience...